# Why Can't I Drain My Hot Water Tank?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I have sediment built up in my hot water tank.  I'm trying to flush it, based on instructions I've found on the internet.  I've turned off the tank completely, attached a hose to the faucet drain and shut off the cold water input line.  I've also turned on the hot water in the kitchen sink and bathroom.

But...every time I shut off of the cold water line, within a few seconds, the water stops flowing (both to the kitchen/bathroom and to the drain).  By turning the cold water on and off, I was able to get a fair bit of sediment out, but I don't understand why I can't get all of the water out of the tank?

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: It sounds like the drain valve is getting plugged up...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Thanks for the comment but what I don't understand is why would the drain valve get unplugged when I turn on the cold water going into the tank?

Answer (score 2):

Open a hot water tap to relieve pressure and plug the drain valve into your garden hose. Turn on the hose for a second (no longer; you don't want to push sediment into the fixtures) to loosen up the sediment.

Comment: Depending on the amount of sediment, it might clog again. Better off using a length of wire if the drain will accommodate a piece of solid wire.